# Cannot read property 'getBlock' of undefined

Tags: web3js, truffle, truffle-deployment

I'm having an issue with running `truffle test` on a Javascript test. I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBlock' of undefined`.

I am trying to get the time of the latest block by using a snippet from OpenZeppelin:

```
async function latestTime () {
  const block = await web3.eth.getBlock('latest');
  return block.timestamp;
}
```

When I run this in `truffle console`,  `web3.eth.getBlock('latest')` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The error message implies that `web3.eth` has not been defined in your JavaScript context.

Make sure you are also including the code which adds the web3 provider:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

  // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
    console.log('No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!')
    // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
  }

  // Now you can start your app & access web3 freely:
  startApp()

})
```

From here: [Web3 - Ethereum Browser Environment Check](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#partly_sunny-web3---ethereum-browser-environment-check)

EDIT: For developing in truffle, the code would look something like this:

```
  initWeb3: function () {
    // Is there an injected web3 instance?
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
      App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
    } else {
      // If no injected web3 instance is detected, fall back to Ganache
      App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');
    }
    web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);

    return App.initContract();
  },
```

Comment: I'm doing this inside of a `truffle test`. Truffle's documentation says that they inject `web3`, so should I have to do this inside of their framework?

Comment: Yes. Even within truffle, you will need to inject a Web3 instance, see my edit above. Also check out [this documentation](https://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/truffle-with-metamask) and [this tutorial](https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop#creating-a-user-interface-to-interact-with-the-smart-contract).

Answer (score 1):

My issue was a versioning problem `truffle console` was running `web3 1.0` while my tests were accessing an injected `web3 0.20` instance. This mean that when I ran my test in an interactive console, it would succeed, but obviously fail when I ran it using `truffle test`.